# "Force" Bluetooth headphones to change connected device under Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, iphone

This feels like one of those, "Yea, that's just how Bluetooth works" questions, but in the year 2018 I'm holding out hope that there's a better answer.

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones, and they're paired to both my Windows 10 PC and my iPhone.

I last listened to my headphones through my iPhone, on my commute home yesterday.

This morning, I'm sitting at my PC and I turn on my headphones, and try to connect my Windows 10 PC to them, and this is what happens:

[image]

They stay "connected" for about 3 seconds, and then I'm assuming get kicked back off because they auto-connected with my previously-used device.

It seems **my only option** is to, *every time* I want to connect my headphones to a different device, go find my phone and manually disconnect them.

Why can't the paired devices (like my PC) tell the headphones, "Hey - you should connect to me now." They're already paired, so it's not a trust issue, it's just a really odd inconvenience that I'm struggling to believe there's no workaround for.

Comment: It is actually much more likely your phone is stealing them back. If it is indeed your headphones’ behavior, there is simply nothing you can do. That would be “Yea, that’s just how your headphones work”. ;)

Comment: @DanielB Yea, I wondered that too. I don't mean to harp on it, but it's crazy to me that this is the state of Bluetooth in 2018 - a bunch of devices fighting each other to connect to a pair of headphones.

Comment: It seems “that’s just how iPhone work”. I have Android phone and always keep Bluetooth on. And my phone never steals connection to my Bluetooth speaker connected to another android phone (when both phones are paired to speaker).

Comment: Turn off Bluetooth via the control center on your iPhone first.  Once connected, you should be able to turn Bluetooth on the iPhone back on and they shouldn’t jump back.

Comment: Yea, it definitely works properly if I manually disconnect the headphones from my phone, but my point is that I shouldn't have to go find the device I'm *not using* and interact with it, to make two other separate devices connect to each other.